# Android NDK get ArrayList error

Tags: android, arraylist, android-ndk

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_androidhellojni_FooFragmentTab_getUserList(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    jint i;
    jclass cls_arraylist = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/ArrayList");
    jmethodID init_arraylist = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_arraylist, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject obj_arraylist = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls_arraylist, init_arraylist, "");
    if (obj_arraylist == NULL) LOGD("obj_arrlist fail");
    jmethodID arraylist_add = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_arraylist, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
    if (arraylist_add == NULL) LOGD("arraylist_add fail");

    jclass cls_int = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID init_int = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_int, "<init>", "(I)V");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        jobject obj_int = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls_int, init_int, i);
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj_arraylist, arraylist_add, obj_int);
    }

    return obj_arraylist;
}
```

This is my sample code to get return ArrayList from C to Java(Android), but compiled and run there exist some error message like:

```
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallObjectMethod does not match boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to CallObjectMethod
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from java.util.ArrayList com.example.androidhellojni.FooFragmentTab.getUserList()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear about what the problem is:

> `the return type of CallObjectMethod does not match boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)`

The `type` in `Call<type>Method` refers to the type of the method, not the type of the method's argument(s). And the type of the method is `boolean`, which is not an `Object`.

Hence you should use `CallBooleanMethod` to call `arraylist_add`.